# asking mercurial to show how much bandwidth it is using -

Tags: debian, bandwidth, mercurial

I have couple of repos. from which I pull sometimes. The default command is `$ hg pull` but that doesn't tell how much bandwidth is being used. I could use `$sudo nethogs` which is a bandwidth monitoring tool but if hg itself could give details of the bandwidth it is using either during pull or push would be nice.

```
[$] hg --version

Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.9.1)
(see https://mercurial-scm.org for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2016 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: [trickle](https://github.com/mariusae/trickle) may help (it's a tool to limit bandwidth usage in a process but I think you can also use it to monitor bandwidth).